# Check what method has been called in a PHP class

Tags: php, class, methods, magic-methods

I need to know which method has been called within a PHP class and handle it within the same class if its possible.

**Example**

```
class Pages
{

    public function firstPage()
    {
        return 'First Page';
    }

    public function secondPage()
    {
        return 'Second Page';
    }

    public function thirdPage($details)
    {
        return view('ThirdPage')->with('details', $details);
    }

    //This will handle everything that happening.
    public function handler($methodExecuted)
    {
        // $methodExecuted will hold what method was accessed.
        echo 'Page ' . $methodExecuted . ' Was accessed';
    }

}
```

Something similar to this, im not sure if this functionality is available to PHP, the "handler" method will just store data to a database in the real app but here its just echoing some data.

Does PHP have a magic method or anything that achieves this? the only thing I've come across so far is the `__call` method but this doesn't do exactly what id want although its sort of on the lines.

Comment: The big questions is why are you looking to do this, what is the end goal of knowing which method is called. In fact, you should already know which method was called, as it is you who wrote the code. So if you could explain a bit more about what it is that you want to accomplish, and not just what you think is the solution to your problem, we might be able to give you better help.

Comment: @ChristianF I need to know which page is being returned so i can add it to a log dynamically as an alternative to writing the code for a new log inside of every single method I have 50+ methods and it seems a little tedious to write the code over and over again, as with most programming languages when you start repeating yourself the language has something to hand that can minimise the repeating process. Apparently PHP doesn't in this specific case anyway.

Comment: Languages don't come with ways to reduce duplication. Programmers do. If you need to add logging, you should use a separate service that is decoupled from your controller logic. Certainly you have some kind of resolver that knows which `Page` object and which `page()` method to call. This resolver is where you should log this information.

Comment: @MadDog I meant speaking simply for example instead of using an if statement over and over again you would use a switch statement, im just giving a simple example, anyways thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no magic method in PHP that is called before each method call. You will have to call this method manually from each method.

Comment: I was afraid of this, so ive got 50+ pages would this be considered good practice to do a new line of code for every single method that returns a page?

Comment: Or rewrite the code to use `__call` method. Or call the `handler` method from the same place where you call the other methods. @ChristianF asked a very good question in a comment to your question, and you should ask this question to yourself.